# Need help identifying part

Tags: components, identification, surface-mount, markings

Hello i have what looks to be a PNP transistor.The marking code on it is U3W with the numbers 65 rotated 90 degrees next to U3W.Its a Sot-23-3 package,refer to image of schematic of how its connected.

Pin A and Pin B are from a RS-485 transceiver,and another note the A,B pins are used to send DMX512 data across it.

Firstly could this be a transistor based on how its connected?If it is do you happen to know the part#,or company,etc?Any input is appreciated thanks.[image]

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65176b.pdf

Comment: Your schematic says it's NPN, but your text says it's PNP.  Which is it?

Comment: You're sure it's not a dual diode, used for over and/or undervoltage or ESD protection?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking dual TVS diode myself...but if it's reading like a PNP, then it's the wrong way 'round to be a dual TVS...

Comment: Not that a simple common-cathode dual (zener/tvs/...) diode would work for RS-485, but there are lots of different kinds of protection parts out there.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It is a PNP.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely the part is some kind of ESD and/or over-voltage protection device.

For example, something like [CDSOT23-SM712](http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/CDSOT23-SM712.pdf), which has asymmetric clamping voltage that seem to be pretty well matched to RS-485 (which can go to +12 V positive but only -7 V negative).

Comment: FWIW, WU3 rather than U3W would likely be Nexperia's [PESD15VS2UT](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESDXS2UT_SERIES.pdf) but this wouldn't deal well with negative signal voltages.